# i want to show an one particular blog have how much likes and how much comment using sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Blog table:

```
| bid  | btitle  |
|  29  | ......  |
|  38  | ......  |
```

likes table:

```
| lid | bid |
|  1  | 29  |
|  2  | 29  |
|  3  | 29  |
|  4  | 38  |
|  5  | 38  |
```

comment table

```
| commid | bid |
|    1   | 29  |
|    2   | 29  |
|    3   | 38  |
```

I had tried the following query but that will not work for me:

```
SELECT blog.bid,blog.btitle,COUNT(likes.lid) AS likecnt,COUNT(comment.comid) AS commentcnt FROM blog,likes,comment WHERE blog.bid=likes.bid AND blog.bid=comment.bid GROUP BY blog.bid
```

i want output like:

```
| bid  | btitle  | likecnt | commentcnt |
|  29  | ......  |   3     |   2        |
|  38  | ......  |   2     |   1        |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `left join` with separate aggregation :

```
select b.bid, b.btitle, 
       coalesce(l.likecnt, 0) as likecnt, 
       coalesce(c.commentcnt, 0) as commentcnt
from blog b left join
     (select l.bid, count(*) as likecnt
      from likes l
      group by l.bid
     ) l
     on l.bid = b.bid left join
     (select c.bid, count(*) as commentcnt
      from comment c
      group by c.bid
     ) c
     on c.bid = l.bid;
```

If you want only matching `bid`s the use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` & remove `COALESCE()`.

Answer (score 1):

Under many circumstances, correlated subqueries may be the fastest solution:

```
select b.bid, b.btitle, 
       (select count(*) from likes l where l.bid = b.bid) as num_likes,
       (select count(*) from comment c where c.bid = b.bid) as num_comments
from blog b;
```

When is this a win performance wise.  First, you want indexes on `likes(bid)` and `comments(bid)`.  With those indexes, it might be the fastest approach for your query.

It is particularly better if you have a `where` clause filtering the blogs in the outer query.  It only has to do the counts for the blogs in the result set.

Comment: @JainamDoshi . . . There were some extraneous characters in the query.  It should work now.

Comment: @Jainam Doshi: Please don't ever say "it doesn't work" without saying *what* doesn't work. Were you getting wrong results? A syntax error? If an error, which message exactly? (BTW: I like Gordon's and Yogesh Sharma's answers much better than the accepted one. Joining unaggregated likes and comments produces a cartesian product, i.e. you combine each like with each comment in a blog unnecessarily, thus blowing up the amount of data to deal with in the query,)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner i got  Query Error: Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'b.id' in 'where clause'

Comment: @Jainam Doshi: Because the table `blog`, here aliased with `b`, doesn't have a column `id`; the column is called `bid`. So, just replace `b.id` with `b.bid` and the query should work. It is surprsing that you have not been able to figure this out yourself. I think the error message is clear and the query very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Use proper joins and count `DISTINCT` values because multiple joins increase the number of returned rows:

```
SELECT b.bid, b.btitle, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT l.lid) AS likecnt,
  COUNT(DISTINCT c.comid) AS commentcnt 
FROM blog b 
LEFT JOIN likes l ON b.bid = l.bid
LEFT JOIN comment c ON b.bid = c.bid 
GROUP BY b.bid, b.btitle
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tkqfZzjh9DvvmwtqugBeqf/1).
I use `LEFT` joins just in case there are no comments or likes for a post.
Results:

```
| bid | btitle | likecnt | commentcnt |
| --- | ------ | ------- | ---------- |
| 29  | ...... | 3       | 2          |
| 38  | ...... | 2       | 1          |
```

Comment: @JainamDoshi is there a reason that you unaccepted the answer?

Comment: @forpas: This is probably caused by a comment I made on Gordon Linoff's answer explaining that unnecessary intermediate cartesian products should be avoided in SQL. While your query solves Jainam's  issue and also explains what he did wrong, it is still the worst approach of all three answers in my opinion.